# Importar un archivo completo desde un archivo .py Python PyQt5

Tags: python, funciones, pyqt5

tengo una ventana la cual tiene un Boton en el medio, aqui esta el codigo:

```
class Prueba(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Prueba, self).__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Visualizador de Radiografias - INICM")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(650, 450)

        self.boton()
        

    def boton(self):

        boton1 = QPushButton("VENTANA 2", self)
        boton1.setObjectName("VENTANA 2")
        boton1.setToolTip("VENTANA 2")
        boton1.setGeometry(200, 180, 280, 45)


        boton1.clicked.connect(self.AccionB1)
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que mediante el boton1 se llame otro .py que es una ventana normal, el .py que quiero llamar es vent2.py, lo que hice fue importar en este codigo **Vent2**, de esta forma:

```
from Vent2 import *
```

y de esta forma lo llamo todo, lo que no se es como llamarlo en la accion del boton1, creo una funcion que ejecute ese codigo, algo asi:

```
def AccionB1(self):

    Vent2.exec_()
```

no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentalo:

**Vent1.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from Vent2 import AccionB1                                       # +++


class Prueba(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Prueba, self).__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Visualizador de Radiografias - INICM")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(650, 450)

        self.accion_b1 = AccionB1()                              # +++
        
        self.boton()
        

    def boton(self):
        boton1 = QPushButton("VENTANA 2", self)
        boton1.setObjectName("VENTANA 2")
        boton1.setToolTip("VENTANA 2")
        boton1.setGeometry(200, 180, 280, 45)
        
#        boton1.clicked.connect(self.AccionB1)
        boton1.clicked.connect(self.accion_b1.show)               # +++
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Prueba()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Vent2.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#def AccionB1(self):
#    Vent2.exec_()

class AccionB1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AccionB1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        
        label = QLabel("<h2>es una ventana normal</h2>", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        vlayout.addWidget(label)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Wow si, muchas gracias si funciono perfectamente, te agradezco mucho :D

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está al final del método boton()

```
 boton1.clicked.connect(self.AccionB1)
```

Esa declaración si iriá en el método **init**. 
¿Por qué? 
Es que debes cargarlo en el **init** para que quede registrado el AccionB1 al momento de ejecutar.

```
class Prueba(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Prueba, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Visualizador de Radiografias - INICM")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |   Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(650, 450)
    
        self.boton()
        boton1.clicked.connect(self.AccionB1)
```

**Nota:**
En dado caso que aún así no funcionará, sería ver como esta el archivo que estás importando, ya que otra manera de abrirlo es crear un método que cargue los componentes que requiere el archivo dos.

Comment: No no me funciona, pero mi pregunta es, si la forma en como llamo el otro .py es correcta, o sea asi:

def AccionB1(self):

    Vent2.exec_()